# How to add several embedded image in the body?

Tags: phpmailer

I am trying to send several images in the body of the email. When I send one it works. But as soon as I want to send several it does not work anymore.

I tried doing a for loop but without result. I have also tried adding addEmbeddedImage several times with a different cid for each image.

```
 if(array_key_exists('submit', $_POST)){
  if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) {
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['userfile']['name']));
    $uploadfile2 = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['userfile2']['name']));

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile) ) {    
            require './vendor/autoload.php';
            $prenom = $_POST['prenom'];
            $nom = $_POST['nom'];
            $q1 = $_POST['q1'];
            $q1_2 = $_POST['q1_2'];
            $q2 = $_POST['q2'];
            $q2_2 = $_POST['q2_2'];
            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            $mail->isHTML(true);
            // $mail->isSMTP();
            // $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
            $mail->Host = 'ssl0.ovh.net';
            $mail->Port = 465;
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
            $mail->setFrom('lol@example.com', $prenom);
            $mail->addAddress('info@nicolaspoulain.be', 'Jessica');
            $mail->Subject = 'Formulaire de sécurité VCA';
            $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($uploadfile, "my-attach");
            $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($uploadfile2, "my-attach2");        
            $mail->Body = 
            '<h1 style= "text-align: center;" margin-bottom:"100px;"> Formulaire de visite sécurité</h1>
            <h4>Prénom: </h4>' . strip_tags($prenom) .
            '<h4>Nom: </h4>' . strip_tags($nom) .
            '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">
            <tr><th style="width: 40%;">Question</th><th style="width: 10%;">Réponse</th><th style="width: 50%;">Commentaires</th></tr>
            <tr style="background: #eee;"><td><strong>Y a-t-il un permis de travail?</strong> </td><td>' . strip_tags($q1) . "</td><td>" . strip_tags($q1_2) . '<img src="cid:my-attach">' . "</td></tr>
            <tr style='background: white;'><td><strong>La description de la tâche et les mesures de sécurité sont-elles suffisamment claires?</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($q2) . "</td><td>" . strip_tags($q2_2) . '<img src="cid:my-attach2">' . "</td></tr>";
            if (!$mail->send()) {
                $msg .= "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
                $msg .= "L'audit a bien été transmis!";
            }
          } else {
              $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
          }
    }   
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by “not working”? On what client?

Comment: I mean that when I want to send 2 different images, there is only one that passes. Still, I get the images in a variable that I call uploadfile and uploadfile2 and I give them 2 different cid. What's wrong?

Comment: Do your calls to `addEmbeddedImage` and `move_uploaded_file` all return `true`? Is the image data present in the message (if you view source on a received message)?

Comment: I edited my message and put my complete code. Maybe it can help. Thank you anyway. By the way, it's only been a few months that I code. Be indulgent ;-)

Comment: Good - so what happens when you check those return values? We can’t do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon,

To be able to add multiple images in the body of the email. You should use CID's.

```
$imgPath = "\images\Progressiva_Itaipu.jpg";
$cid = md5($imgPath);
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($imgPath,$cid,'Progressiva_Itaipu.jpg');
```

Calling so in the body of the message

```
$message .= "<img src='cid:$cid'>";
```

If it is multiple images, you can do the foreach or even a for